# concatenate on tooltip from data array in chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to get these four data values from the array and I want to display them on the tooltip along with the % symbol at the end.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Net Profit Margin',
                    data:[, 18, 19, 21, 20,]

                },
                {
                    label: 'Gross Profit Margin',
                    data:  [, 57, 54, 57, 59,]
                },
            ]
        },
```

and in the tooltip, I am trying to get the data so that I can display it by using callbacks.

```
tooltip: {
                 
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function (tooltipItem) {
                            output = myChart.data.datasets[0].data[]
                        }
                    }


                },
```

Now I want to know should I write in data[___] in order to get the first object when I hover on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the [tooltip label callback,](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback) you also need to define [interaction mode 'dataset'](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html#dataset).

```
options: {
  interaction: {
    mode: 'dataset'
  },
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      callbacks: {
        label: context => context.label + ': ' + context.formattedValue + '%'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works.

```js
var myChart = new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Net Profit Margin',
        data: [18, 19, 21, 20]
      },
      {
        label: 'Gross Profit Margin',
        data: [57, 54, 57, 59]
      },
    ]
  },
  options: {
    interaction: {
      mode: 'dataset'
    },
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: context => context.label + ': ' + context.formattedValue + '%'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="80"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying for such a long time for this. Seriously means alot to me.