# How can I display the percentage symbol inside the chartjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I can already retrieve the correct values for the percentage. How can I display the percentage symbol for each of the values?
the codes for the graph:

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69159984/2358409

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tooltips can be modified thus

```
    <Line
      data={{
<snip>
      options={{
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Hello",
          fontSize: 20
        },
        plugins: {
          tooltip: {
              callbacks: {
                  label: function(context) {
                      var label = context.dataset.label || '';
                      if (context.parsed.y !== null) {
                          label += ' ' +context.parsed.y + '%';
                      }
                      return label;
                  }
              }
          }
      },
        scales: {
          y: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            ticks: {
              stepSize: 20,
              callback: function (value, index, values) {
                return value + " %";
              }
            }
          }
        },
        legend: {
          labels: {
            fontSize: 25
          }
        }
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the `ticks` property like this:

```js
scales: {
    y: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        ticks: {
            stepSize: 20,
            callback: function(value, index, values) {
                return value + " %";
            }            
        }
    }
},
```

Found that here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats

Seems to do the trick:

[image]

Comment: I added it and there's no percentage symbol if I'll hover on it - https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-and-reduce-data-per-month-forked-cy4bl?file=/src/App.js&fbclid=IwAR2-kG5GC-t_s9ueFJBvSsYIGkNeDWYITgBnCcTbIoGKls769fyO_hpHtvA

Comment: Ohhh, I thought you meant for the ticks.

Comment: I just wanted to put a percentage symbol on it. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but I don't know how to do that. It looks like some kind of custom tooltip, as referenced here: https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/issues/151